# How to override new Gutenberg product loop block markup

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

Recently updated WP and plugins. The "Products by Category" block I had in the Gutenberg editor are now rendered very differently.

After quite some digging, it appears that the `WGPB_Block_Grid_Base` `render` and `render-product` functions are now defining the appearance of the content. This is ignoring much of my custom action and markup work present before now for this block.

This is a completely different animal, looking at it I'm not even sure where to begin. There's a filter applying directly to markup inline inside filter apply:

```
    return apply_filters(
        'woocommerce_blocks_product_grid_item_html',
        "<li class=\"wc-block-grid__product\">
            <a href=\"{$data->permalink}\" class=\"wc-block-grid__product-link\">
                {$data->image}
                {$data->title}
            </a>
            {$data->price}
            {$data->badge}
            {$data->rating}
            {$data->button}
        </li>",
        $data,
        $product
    );
```

Is there an easy way to override the templates they're using? Or am I basically stuck writing my own entire Gutenberg block plugin to get this back to where it was?

Comment: why not just use the supplied filter ?  `add_filter(        'woocommerce_blocks_product_grid_item_html', function(){return ' your custom markup' });`

Answer (score 11):

We wanted to change the position of the add-to-cart button and product name and add a wrapper for the thumbnail so we modified the output with some custom markup in a function like so...

```
function my_product_block( $html, $data, $product ) {
    $html = '<li class="wc-block-grid__product">
        <div class="image-wrap">
            <a href="' . $data->permalink . '" class="wc-block-grid__product-link">' . $data->image . '</a>
            ' . $data->button . '
        </div>
        <h3><a href="' . $data->permalink . '">' . $data->title . '</a></h3>
        ' . $data->badge . '
        ' . $data->price . '
        ' . $data->rating . '
    </li>';
    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_blocks_product_grid_item_html', 'my_product_block', 10, 3);
```

Comment: this is a good answer, however the filter can't be applied to "All Products" block, is there a way to apply a filter to "all Products" block?

Comment: I would like to know this as well. There has to be a way to intercept this loop and adjust product data.

Answer (score 1):

```
function my_product_block( $html, $data, $product ) {
    global $product;
    $newness_days = 30;
    $html = '<li class="wc-block-grid__product">';
    if ( ( time() - ( 60 * 60 * 24 * $newness_days ) ) < $created) {
    $html .= '<div class="image-wrap"><span class="itsnew">' . esc_html__( 'New!', 'woocommerce' ) . '</span>
            </div>
        <h3><a href="' . $data->permalink . '">' . $data->title . '</a></h3>
        ' . $data->badge . '
        ' . $data->price . '
        ' . $data->rating . '
    ';
    }
    else
    {
        $html .= '<div class="image-wrap">
        <h3><a href="' . $data->permalink . '">' . $data->title . '</a></h3>
        ' . $data->badge . '
        ' . $data->price . '
        ' . $data->rating . '
    ';
    }
    $html .= '</li>';
    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_blocks_product_grid_item_html', 'my_product_block', 10, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I went through this recently and I was able to modify the render with the following function:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_blocks_product_grid_item_html', 'change_render_product', 10, 3);

function change_render_product( $html, $data, $product ) {
  $search = '<div class="wc-block-grid__product-title">';
  $add    = '<p>text for example</p>'.$search;
  $output = str_replace($search, $add, $html);

  return $output;
}
```

In my case, I added an element above the title.

Answer (score 0):

Custom Field Suite

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_blocks_product_grid_item_html', 'my_custom_render_product_block', 10, 3);
function my_custom_render_product_block( $html, $data, $post ) {
    $productID = url_to_postid( $data->permalink );
    $product = wc_get_product( $productID );

    $p_img = CFS()->get( 'p_img' , $productID );
    if( $p_img ){ 
        $p_img = '<img src="' . esc_url($p_img) . '" alt="" decoding="async">';
    } else { $p_img = $data->image; }

    return '
    <li class="wc-block-grid__product">
        <a href="'.$product->get_permalink().'">
            <span class="my-thumbnail">' . $p_img . '</span>
            <span>' . $product->get_title() . '</span>
        </a>
    </li>
';
}
```

Comment: 3rd param which you defined as `$post` is actually `$product` in WooCommerce defined filter which means you have `WC_Product` object, hence you don't have to do `url_to_postid` and `wc_get_product` there, you can simply use passed param.